# Basis tranformation from surface embebed in $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: classical-mechanics, differential-geometry, linear-algebra

I have a set particles that are located on a surface on $\mathbb{R}^3$. To make it more clear, I am working with a triangulated surface, and, because this triangulation is reasonably detailed, grossly speaking one can consider that, on the domain of a given particle and its nearest neighbours (NN), the surface is flat.

I try to express the coordinates of a particle and its NN such that I have coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^2$. In other words, I would expect a transformation resulting in a a null value in one of the coordinate axis allowing me to calculate properties on the plane.

My approach is to find the Inertia tensor $\mathbf{I}$ of the particle of interest and its NN with respect to the centre of mass,  $\mathbf{I_{cm}} := \mathbf{I}( \mathbf{r - R_{cm}) }$. Then, I diagonalize $\mathbf{I}$ such that the set eigenvectors $\mathbf{v_i}, i \in\{1,2,3 \}$, define a new basis system:
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{B} := \begin{pmatrix} v_1^x & v_2^x & v_3^x \\
                              v_1^y & v_2^y & v_3^y \\ 
                              v_1^z & v_2^z & v_3^z
               \end{pmatrix} 
\end{equation}

In a last step, I can determine the coordinates of the particles attending to that basis as 
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\mathbf{r'} = \mathbf{B}^{-1}(\mathbf{r - R_{cm}} )\\
            = \mathbf{B}^{T}(\mathbf{r - R_{cm}} ),
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where the last equality comes from the orthonormality of between the vectors in $\mathbf{B}$.

I have been doing tests with MWEs and its seems to work, resulting in values of $\mathbf{r'}$ where one of the values is zero. Of course, it is only exactly 0 if the particles are perfectly defined into a plane. Still, this seems to work reasonably, such that one of the coordinates can be considered negligible with respect to to the others, up to the 30% of variability in the location of the particles on the original coordinates but when I go to my surface of interest it does not work good, despite they are within this regime.

What are your thought on the procedure? Maybe I have something wrong on my codes and not on the maths?

Thanks for your help

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? It sounds like you have three particles defining a plane and want to obtain basis vectors spanning that plane (which is much simpler than what you are doing).

Comment: I have more than three particles. Of course, with only three particles you can define the normal vector and thus the associated plane. If you have more particles you need to evaluate all the possible normal vectors attending to the triangulation and average them. This is a possibility that I already have considered, but It should be possible to do it without the explicit evaluation of the normal vectors in terms of a linear transformation